# JavaScript/React Native: How can I make RN component only visible within the same folder?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using Container for each of my component Views. Container wraps the View component. View only has `return ( <View><Text>..... )`, while Container handles logic and states and provides all necessary information to the View via props. Here is a pseudo example:

BarChartView.js:

```
export default function BarChartView({ chartData, onChartDataPress }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <SomeCanvas>
        <SomeBarChart data={chartData} onPress={onChartDataPress} />
      </SomeCanvas>
    </View>
  );
}
```

BarChartViewContainer.js:

```
export default function BarChartViewContainer() {
  const chartData = [
    { quarter: 1, earnings: 13000 },
    { quarter: 2, earnings: 16500 },
    { quarter: 3, earnings: 14250 },
    { quarter: 4, earnings: 19000 },
  ];

  const onChartDataPress = () => {
    doMagic();
  };

  return <BarChartView chartData={chartData, onChartDataPress}/>;
}
```

**Problem:** BarChartView and BarChartViewContainer are located in the same folder as src/components/barChart. App.js located in src/ and is able to access both. I would like to restrict the access to BarChartView within the same package/folder as it is possible in Java with packageScope. E.g if I create a class without any modifier in Java, then I can only access it within the same package/folder. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html. Is it possible to achieve something similar in React Native with JavaScript?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to exclude `BarChartView` from some intellisense/auto-complete in your IDE, such as when adding an import statement from a component?

Comment: @David not exactly. I would like to restrict the access to BarChartView within the same package/folder as it is possible in Java with packageScope. E.g if I create a class without any modifier in Java, then I can only access it within the same package/folder. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html. I have rephrased my question so that it's more clear.

Comment: I think this is just not done in JS land, commonly. It's a best practice to move such a single-use module into a subfolder mabye, to signal that it's only supposed to be used by a certain parent. You don't have to do access control against developers on the same codebase this way (within the module import system). If it's a library, you would simply not export the module on the top level if you don't want it to be used elsewhere.